# Change root folder name in tar.gz file

Tags: linux, tar

I have a tar.gz file, specifically: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u20-b26/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz. I am going to download this, change it and stick it in my own repository.

I wish to change the name of the root directory that gets extracted without actually extracting, changing, then compressing again manually in separate commands. This is so that anyone that extracts it in the future, will have my specified folder name.

I know I can use the `--transform` option but that is **NOT** what I want, I don't want my users to have to specify this option.

Is this possible?

If not, is there a one liner that does the extraction, change and compression in such a way that doesn't change the permissions or structure etc...

Comment: `download && extract && mv folder_old folder_new`? Can you describe the usecase?

Comment: @Jan - its going in my own repository, I don't want the user to have to go through any extra steps to change it, I want them to be able to simply extract it and the folder name be correct.

Comment: if you're going to put it into you repo, then why don't you extract, change, repack and _then_ put it into your repo?

Comment: it's not possible to change .tar (the archive) before uncompressing it

Answer (score 1):

Here's your one liner, RUN AS ROOT or with `sudo` to preserve permissions, etc.

`gunzip -c jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar --transform=EXPRESSION xf - ; tar cf fixed.tar DIRNAME ; gzip fixed.tar`

Sorry I can't help you on what you want the EXPRESSION/DIRNAME to be, just not enough info in the question to be able to help there.